# Outlook rule with space as a part of a matching string

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, rules

In my Outlook 2010 rule "`except when a message header contains`" I have `'RE: ' or 'FW: '`. (I would actually very much prefer to have such rule on a Title alone but did not see such option.)

Outlook seems to exclude everything that has `RE`, for example "no-**re**ply".

Is there a way to enforce the rule, including punctuation mark (colon) and space?

Answer (score 1):

You may try the "except if the subject contains specific words" exception:

[image]